# Does Hacker News have an API?

Tags: hacker-news

I have looked around, and the answer seems to be no. But, I wanted to make sure, hence my question here. I am interested in writing a Hacker News client app, so am looking for an API.

I see there are some third-party (unofficial ones) out there; but how do I know which is good, bad or just OK? Then there is the problem that Hacker News could pull the plug on these unofficial APIs at any time, thus rendering a client application useless.

I assume that all existing client apps use one of these other APIs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone has started maintaining an "Unofficial" HackerNewsAPI in github:

https://github.com/thekarangoel/HackerNewsAPI

(I have no first hand experience of using this API)

**UPDATE Oct 7 2014:
Hacker News has an [official API](http://blog.ycombinator.com/hacker-news-api)** :

> Today we’re excited to launch an
>   official Hacker News API. We’ve partnered up with Firebase (YC S11) so
>   that the data we’re making available will be near real time, which
>   should be a huge improvement for developers who had to rely on
>   scraping the site for this info.
>
> The API is available at https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/ with some
>   initial documentation and a few examples written by our own Nick Sivo
>   on the Hacker News Github account. Currently, it’s read only, but we
>   hope to improve it over time and may later enable access to private
>   per-user data using OAuth.

Comment: I am the owner and maintainer of this repo. I'm continuously working on making this API work perfectly. PR's welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hacker News just launched their **official API**:

https://github.com/HackerNews/API